# Using GitLab LFS with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, egit, git-lfs

I have some problems by using GitLab LFS with eclipse. I did the following steps:

1. enabled LFS on GitLab server
2. created a now project for testing LFS
3. installed a new eclipse ide (2020-09)
4. installed additional eGit LFS support and activated it for the current user
5. created a new .gitattributes and pushed it to the project
6. tried to add and push a file (*.bin) which is listed in the .gitattributes

Here an error message occurs: Can't connect to any repository: git@ ... .git (no protocol: null/info/lfs/objects/batch).
Does anybody have an idea what I do wrong. Somehow I managed to push LFS in a previous set up but unfortunately I can't reconstruct the right settings.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments I found a solution. My mistake was to change the remote name during the clone process. After cloning with the default value (origin) the error has disappeared. Maybe there is anyone who can explain this.